# Disable Swagger on Node/Express API

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I'm using Swagger to document my Node/Express API on my dev environment. It's working perfectly but now I need to disable it when going to production, in order to not let the API definition publicly reachable.

Is there a way to do it, using some npm script for example ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use environment variables to check. For instance:
if (proccess.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    // allow route
}

and that environment variable can be saved in a .env file and loaded with https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv for instance

Comment: Thanks, it looks great :) So, tell me if I m wrong but, assuming I've a variable named "isProduction", should I have to manually set it to "true" before going on production, or is there any way to automate this ?

Comment: Ideally you should have a `.env` file with all your environment-dependant variables. In production that file will have same keys but different values than in development. For instance, your API keys should be configured that way too.

Comment: Ok. So using dotenv, I'm able to tell the lib if I'm on prod or dev ? (sorry, didn't have time yet to read the documentation accurately)

Answer (score 4):

Keeping in line with convention, you wanna set NODE_ENV environment variable (environment variables are values set on OS, with no dependence to your app) to make things depend on the environment you're currently on. This'll heavily depend on where do you host your production app.

- If it's an AWS ECS deployment, you'll need to set it in AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store for example.
- Or if it's just a vanilla cloud instance that you ssh into, you probably run your app with something along the lines of `node app.js` or `npm run start` (Or maybe you're using docker and your script ends with one of these commands.) In any case, before the execution of the "run application" command, make sure environment is set to production via `export NODE_ENV=production` command. You can check whether it worked via `echo $NODE_ENV` command.
- Or in case you're using docker-compose, you can set env vars as such:
  [image: it says development here but you'll set it to production]

Anyhow, once you're sure that NODE_ENV is production when the app is running in production, and with these assumptions:

- your application is named "app" in your startup file and you define middlewares as "app.use(..."
- your swagger route is something like "http://localhost:PORT/docs"

With these assumptions, make it so that this is the first "app.use" type, middleware definition in your code:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
  app.use('/docs', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send("Not Found");
  });
}
```

If any of the assumptions I've made does not pertain to your case, adjust them accordingly. And you're done.

Comment: Thanks ! Very clear :) But, in your "if" statement, did you rather mean "== "production"" instead of "!==" ?

Comment: yeah, edited shortly after I think. But, it's better form to use triple equals signs rather than two: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Since it does not do the type conversion, it's faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

If using `swagger-express-mw` and `swagger-tools` for **swagger-UI**

This is how i do the same inside my app.js

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  SwaggerExpress.create(config, function (err, swaggerExpress) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    app.use(SwaggerUi(swaggerExpress.runner.swagger));
    // install middleware
    swaggerExpress.register(app);

    app.listen(PORT);
  });
} else {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started @ Port - ${PORT}`));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of or in addition to disabling the Swagger UI, you might also choose to access protect it. Here's how we did *both* using HTTP Basic Auth. In your `main.ts` or equivalent, here with a Node.js application using NEST:

```
const customNestApplication = (app: INestApplication) => {

  // [...]

  const swaggerEnabled = configService.get('swagger.enabled', { infer: true });

  if (
    swaggerEnabled &&
    configService.get('swagger.auth.user', { infer: true }) &&
    configService.get('swagger.auth.password', { infer: true })
  ) {
    app.use(
      `${configService.get('swagger.path', { infer: true })}`,
      basicAuth({
        challenge: true,
        users: {
          [configService.get('swagger.auth.user', { infer: true })]: 
          configService.get('swagger.auth.password', { infer: true }),
        },
      }),
    );
  }

  // Set up Swagger as usual, etc.
  // [...]

  return app.listen(port);
};
```

See also [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802703) specifically about Swagger auth, for more details.