# Is it possible to add Authentication to access to NestJS' Swagger Explorer

Tags: typescript, swagger-ui, openapi, nestjs

I'm currently using Swagger in my NestJS project, and I have the explorer enabled:

in `main.js`

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('My App')
    .setSchemes('https')
    .setDescription('My App API documentation')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build()

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options)
SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document, {
    customSiteTitle: 'My App documentation',
})
```

With this, the explorer is accessible in `/docs` which is what I expected. But I was wondering if it's possible to add any Authentication layer to the explorer, so only certain requests are accepted.

I want to make this explorer accessible in production, but only for authenticated users.

Comment: Most of the time, the way I see this is people pull explorer _out_ of their production instance...

Comment: I would suggest to add a security in your reverse proxy (apache or nginx or varnish etc). Quite easy to add a rule with basic auth or blocking the access for instance. If you really want to manage it within Nest, using a Middleware should do the trick

Comment: Yeah, I my plan was to use one of the middlewares we have for the application, but maybe move this to a different layer (or even remove from production altogether is the only way) :)

Comment: @zenbeni I want to do that, however, I can't send authorization headers within iframe src or browser url, how did you solve that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Securing access to your Swagger with HTTP Basic Auth using NestJS with Express**

First run `npm i express-basic-auth` then add the following to your `main.{ts,js}`:

```
import * as basicAuth from "express-basic-auth";

// ...

// Sometime after NestFactory add this to add HTTP Basic Auth
app.use(
  // Paths you want to protect with basic auth
  "/docs*",
  basicAuth({
    challenge: true,
    users: {
      yourUserName: "p4ssw0rd",
    },
  })
);

// Your code
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle("My App")
  .setSchemes("https")
  .setDescription("My App API documentation")
  .setVersion("1.0")
  .build();

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
SwaggerModule.setup(
  // Make sure you use the same path just without `/` and `*`
  "docs",
  app,
  document,
  {
    customSiteTitle: "My App documentation",
  }
);

// ...
```

With this in place you will be prompted on any of the `/docs` route with a HTTP Basic Auth prompt. We add the `*` to also protect the generated JSON (`/docs-json`) and YAML (`/docs-json`) OpenAPI files. If you have any other route beginning with `/docs`, that should not be protected, you should rather explicitly name the routes you want to protect in an array `['/docs', '/docs-json', '/docs-yaml']`.

You should not put the credentials in your code/repository but rather in your `.env` and access via the [ConfigService](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration).

I have seen this solution first [here](https://manuel-heidrich.dev/blog/how-to-secure-your-openapi-specification-and-swagger-ui-in-a-nestjs-application/).

Comment: Because there is also a /docs-yaml endpoint I ended up specifying `['/docs*'`]

Answer (score 39):

Just add `.addBearerAuth()` (without any parameters) to your swagger options

and `@ApiBearerAuth()` to your Controller methods

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('My App')
    .setSchemes('https')
    .setDescription('My App API documentation')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth()
    .build()
```

Comment: I assumed the top level bearer would apply it to everything, but I was wrong -- I guess you really do need it on every controller.

Edit: is there any way to persist the authentication between refreshes?

Comment: Better solution then using @ApiBearerAuth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269804/how-to-globally-apply-swagger-uis-apibearerauth-instead-of-applying-for-each

Answer (score 34):

**Updated following breaking/API changes in @nestjs/swagger version 4.0.**

Hi,
Took a lot of try&fail to get this right.
The comments in the code is what is important to understand. The names rely on each other for this to work.

**main.ts**

```
    const options = new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle('my-title')
        .setDescription('my-descirption')
        .setVersion('1.0')
        .addBearerAuth(
          {
            type: 'http',
            scheme: 'bearer',
            bearerFormat: 'JWT',
            name: 'JWT',
            description: 'Enter JWT token',
            in: 'header',
          },
          'JWT-auth', // This name here is important for matching up with @ApiBearerAuth() in your controller!
        )
        .build();
      const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
      SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
```

And in your controller you do the following (note @ApiBearerAuth() using the same name as the name on the swagger options in main.ts):

**app.controller.ts**

```
    @Roles(Role.Admin)
      @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
      @ApiTags('Admin')
      @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get admin section' })
      @Get('admin')
      @ApiBearerAuth('JWT-auth') // This is the one that needs to match the name in main.ts
      getAdminArea(@Request() req) {
        return req.user;
      }
```

Hope this saves somebody the time it took me to understand what was going on.

Comment: Ugh, finally. This is the only write-up that actually explained it well enough for my idiot brain to get it. One additional thing that could be added is that `@ApiBearerAuth('JWT-auth')` can be used as a decorator on the entire controller class, too. like `@Controller('users') @ApiBearerAuth('JWT-auth') export class UserController {...}` You can also put `.addSecurityRequirements('JWT-auth')` before `.build()` in the `main.ts` to apply that auth scheme to the whole system.

Answer (score 23):

UPDATE

As per recent changes in `DocumentBuilder` methods, this how it worked for me. Sharing for the people who are using new versions.

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
.setTitle('My API')
.setDescription('API used for testing purpose')
.setVersion('1.0.0')
.setBasePath('api')
.addBearerAuth(
  { type: 'http', scheme: 'bearer', bearerFormat: 'JWT' },
  'access-token',
)
.build();

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
```

**Update** Also, please use `@ApiBearerAuth()` on your controller function to add auth.

```
@Get('/test')
@ApiBearerAuth()
```

`access-token` is the name for reference in swagger doc. Your token in the header will be passed as below:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:3004/test" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer test-token"
```

Comment: Somehow this does not work for me, the header does not get applied to the request - the curl output stays - curl -X GET "http://localhost:3000/unit-type" -H "accept: */*"

Comment: @Jacobdo can you see lock icon on your endpoint in swagger doc? You can click on it and pass the access token, if not then you need to add `@ApiBearerAuth()` in controller function, see updated answer

Comment: This tells about the security of your endpoints, not the swagger itself.

Comment: just 
`.addBearerAuth({ in: 'header', type: 'http' })`

Comment: The question is about securing access to the swagger page itself, not showing the auth options on routes swagger displays. See my answer for actually securing your `/docs` endpoint with HTTP Basic Auth.

Answer (score 8):

**THIS IS FOR APIKEY NOT BEARER**

In case somebody gets to this post and looking for `apiKey` (instead of bearer) you need to follow this

in main.ts

```
    const options = new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle('CMOR')
        .setDescription('CMOR API documentation')
        .setVersion('1.0')
        .addServer('/api')
        .addApiKey({
            type: 'apiKey', // this should be apiKey
            name: 'api-key', // this is the name of the key you expect in header
            in: 'header',
        }, 'access-key' // this is the name to show and used in swagger
        ) 
        .build();
```

then in your controller or methods

```
@ApiTags('analyzer')
@ApiSecurity('access-key') // this is the name you set in Document builder
@Controller('analyzer')
export class ScreenAnalyzerController {
```

Answer (score 5):

The following example is working very well

`.addBearerAuth({ in: 'header', type: 'http' })`

You should tell where is the token location in the `in` prop

and since you override the default options you should pass the `type`

```
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Api docs for mobile')
    .setDescription('The api docs for the mobile application')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth({ in: 'header', type: 'http' })
    .build();
```

the `addBearerAuth` implementation

```js
    addBearerAuth(options = {
        type: 'http'
    }, name = 'bearer') {
        this.addSecurity(name, Object.assign({ scheme: 'bearer', bearerFormat: 'JWT' }, options));
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

after adding `.addBearerAuth()` to your swagger options, you should add `@ApiBearerAuth()` to your Controller or it's methods.

**NOTE:** in order to keep token in swagger UI in browser after refreshing page you should set this in swagger options:

```
SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document, {
    swaggerOptions: {
        persistAuthorization: true, // this
    },
});
```

Comment: a good solution

Answer (score 4):

For anyone with similar challenge, you can add Authentication to your Swagger UI in Nestjs as shown below.

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
.setTitle('Sample Project API')
.setDescription('This is a sample project to demonstrate auth in Swagger UI')
.setVersion('1.0')
.addTag('Nestjs Swagger UI')
.setContactEmail('your_contact@mail.com')
.addBearerAuth('Authorization', 'header', 'basic')
.setBasePath('api')
.build();
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);
```

So .addBearerAuth takes 3 arguments (key-name, location, authentication-type). authorization-type can be `basic`, `bearer` or `apikey`

Comment: I got an error when specifying "bearer" as the authentication-type to the .addBearerAuth method. Turns out if you just don't include the third parameter, it enables bearer authentication. Using the 'basic' value did turn on username/password http auth-

Comment: they made a huge change on the DocumentBuilder methods and their params, I hope someone makes an example of this changes.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wants authentication globally, u can add .addSecurityRequirements behind .build(). Don't worry login router will not effect, it depend on ur logic it require token or not.

```
 const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(
      app,
      new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle('Book store')
        .setDescription('The Book store API description')
        .setVersion('1.0')
        .addBearerAuth(
          {
            type: 'http',
            scheme: 'Bearer',
            bearerFormat: 'JWT',
            in: 'header',
          },
          'token',
        )
        .addSecurityRequirements('token')
        .build(),
    );

    // access http://localhost:${PORT}/docs
    SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);
    app.use('/apidoc-json/', (req: Request, res: any) => res.send(document));
```

Comment: thanks! After so many trial-error, your way worked!

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by adding `addApiKey` or `addBearerAuth` examples of which are described in other answers to this question.

From my side, I can add OAuth2 authentication
There are some differences in implementation between @nestjs/swagger3** and  @nestjs/swagger4**

> **For the @nestjs/swagger3****

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('API')
    .setDescription('API')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .setSchemes('https', 'http')
    .addOAuth2('implicit', AUTH_URL, TOKEN_URL)
    .build();

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);

SwaggerModule.setup(swaggerPath, app, document, {
    swaggerOptions: {
        oauth2RedirectUrl: REDIRECT_URL, // after successfully logging
        oauth: {
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        },
    },
});
```

The addOAuth2 also supports flows as password, application and accessCode

> **For the @nestjs/swagger4****

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('API')
    .setDescription('API description')
    .setVersion(version)
    .addServer(host)
    .addOAuth2(
        {
            type: 'oauth2',
            flows: {
                implicit: {
                    authorizationUrl: AUTH_URL + `?nonce=${getRandomNumber(9)}`, // nonce parameter is required and can be random, for example nonce=123456789
                    tokenUrl: TOKEN_URL,
                    scopes: SCOPES, // { profile: 'profile' }
                },
            },
        },
        'Authentication'
    )
    .build();

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);

SwaggerModule.setup(swaggerPath, app, document, {
    swaggerOptions: {
        oauth2RedirectUrl: REDIRECT_URL, // after successfully logging
        oauth: {
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: I followed this demo with the swagger4 but I'm having an issue with the scopes object, To register the API I used the scopeURL, and when I  set only the name like you suggested **profile**, I get an error which says that I can't request this scope

Comment: Actually, I have not used the scopeURL. I have set the scope as an object like in an example. and there can be added many properties like `{profile: 'profile', email:'email', ...}`.  The value of `scopes` can be also an array, like `['profile', 'email', ...]`. But I'm not sure that you can use scopeURL as a value of the `scope` parameter since it can't be a string. You can check the module codes and see that.

Answer (score 2):

In your main.ts file add this

```
 const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('App title')
    .setDescription("Api description")
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('ApiTag')
    .setContact('name', 'ulr', "email")
    .addBearerAuth({ type: 'http', schema: 'Bearer', bearerFormat: 'Token' } as SecuritySchemeObject, 'Bearer')
    .build();
```

Controller file

```
@ApiBearerAuth("Bearer")
@Controller('posts')
export class PostController {
  constructor(private readonly postService: PostService) { }
}
```

[Set your token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cjay.png)

Comment: In Your controller add this    @ApiBearerAuth("Bearer")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is not able to solve with the above answers.

Here is how I was able to add the bearer token

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
.setTitle('My API')
.setDescription('My api')
.setVersion('1.0.0')
.addBearerAuth(
  {
    type: 'http',
    scheme: 'bearer',
    bearerFormat: 'JWT',
    name: 'JWT',
    description: 'Enter JWT token',
    in: 'header',
  },
  'token'
)
.build();
```

Once you add this don't forget to add the decorator `@ApiBearerAuth('token')`

And one more thing to notice here is the second argument in the `.addBearerAuth({...}, 'token')` method needs to add in the decorator then only you will be able to see the Authorization in the curl request.

```
@Controller('api')
@ApiBearerAuth('token')
```

You can keep it empty too `@ApiBearerAuth()` and remove the second argument from the

```
.addBearerAuth(
{
    type: 'http',
    scheme: 'bearer',
    bearerFormat: 'JWT',
    name: 'JWT',
    description: 'Enter JWT token',
    in: 'header',
})
```

NestJS documentation needs to be improved

Comment: it'd be even better if it didn't require the `@ApiBearerAuth` decorator on controllers/routes.

Answer (score 0):

based on previous answers, you may see this error (if you want to use `express-basic-auth` module

```
Type 'typeof expressBasicAuth' has no call signatures.

Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead
```

for this situation you can use `.default` in main.ts

```
import * as basicAuth from 'express-basic-auth';

async function bootstrap() {

  app.use(['/docs'], basicAuth.default({
    challenge: true,
    users: {
      [process.env.SWAGGER_USERNAME]: process.env.SWAGGER_PASSWORD,
    },
  }));

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
      .setTitle('api')
      .setDescription('API description')
      .setVersion('1.0')
      .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that uses the root as the swagger endpoint, you can do this:

```js
import basicAuth from "express-basic-auth";
import { Request } from "express";

app.use(["/", "/-json"], function (req: Request, res, next) {
  if (req.accepts().includes("application/json")) {
    next();
  } else {
    const auth = basicAuth({
      challenge: true,
      users: {
        [process.env.SWAGGER_USER]: process.env.SWAGGER_PASSWORD,
      },
    });
    auth(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](https://trilon.io/blog/nestjs-swagger-tips-tricks#secure-openapi-documentation-usernamepassword) in case you want to protect access to the swagger page `/api-docs` i.e only users with access can view the page have the below code in `main.ts`

```
 const apiDocumentationCredentials = {
  name: 'admin',
  pass: 'admin',
};
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<INestApplication>(ApplicationModule);
  const httpAdapter = app.getHttpAdapter();
  httpAdapter.use('/api-docs', (req, res, next) => {
    function parseAuthHeader(input: string): { name: string; pass: string } {
      const [, encodedPart] = input.split(' ');
      const buff = Buffer.from(encodedPart, 'base64');
      const text = buff.toString('ascii');
      const [name, pass] = text.split(':');
      return { name, pass };
    }
    function unauthorizedResponse(): void {
      if (httpAdapter.getType() === 'fastify') {
        res.statusCode = 401;
        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
      } else {
        res.status(401);
        res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
      }
      next();
    }
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
      return unauthorizedResponse();
    }
    const credentials = parseAuthHeader(req.headers.authorization);
    if (
      credentials?.name !== apiDocumentationCredentials.name ||
      credentials?.pass !== apiDocumentationCredentials.pass
    ) {
      return unauthorizedResponse();
    }
    next();
  });
}
```