# How to globally apply Swagger UI's @ApiBearerAuth() instead of applying for each controller

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I am working on a nestJS based api, and I am using Swagger UI documentation. I want keep the functionality of @ApiBearerAuth() for all my controllers, however I wish to have this as a global feature. That way every time I create new routes or endpoints it will already be covered.

From the https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/security documentation:

```
@ApiBearerAuth()
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {}
```

This is what I am following now, but is there a way to set this globally?

Comment: I think this is impossible by default, but there is a great lib that might helps you achieve it, and it's name is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@golevelup/nestjs-discovery using it you should be able to build your own module to make it without any additional problems.

Comment: Reading up on this package, it seems as if this will allow me to find all the methods using a specific decorator. However it doesn't seem like I can use this to find all the @Controllers and also doesn't look like there is a way to add in a decorator you want. Is there any example/tutorial out there.

Answer (score 6):

In the source code of `@nestjs/swagger` its visible that `addBearerAuth()` sets the security `name` to "bearer" so it is possible to use `addBearerAuth()` and `addSecurityRequirements('bearer')`:

```
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
  ...
  .addBearerAuth()
  .addSecurityRequirements('bearer')
  .build();
```

Comment: That worked for me, note that you have to add only the token in the Authorization input.
For example `eyJhbGciOiJS...Ysntw`,  not `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJS...Ysntw`.

Comment: Also, don't forget you will need to add the @ApiBearerAuth() decorator to every protected route. This way, you only have to set the authorization token once in swagger  (from the global "Authorize" button at the top) and have it bubble down to every protected endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in your DocumentBuilder you may add:

```
.addSecurity('ApiKeyAuth', {
    type: 'apiKey',
    in: 'header',
    name: 'Authorization',
})
.addSecurityRequirements('ApiKeyAuth')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hack, because I use ApiTags in every Controller so that I create a new decorator

```
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';

export function ApiTagsAndBearer(...tags: string[]) {
  return applyDecorators(
    ApiBearerAuth(), //
    ApiTags(...tags),
  );
}
```