# In NestJS, what is the decorator I can add at a controller level to add an Authorization header to my Swagger docs?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, openapi, authorization-header

I'm using NestJS 7.6.11.  I have the following decorators on my controller ...

```
@Controller('private')
@ApiTags('MyObjects')
@ApiConsumes('application/json')
@ApiProduces('application/json')
@UseInterceptors(new JwtInterceptor())
export class MyController {
```

Is there any decorator I can add that would result in Swagger (OpenAPI 3) documentation being generated such that it indicates that all methods in my controller need to have an "authorization" header?

**Edit:** In response the answer given I added the @ApiHeader so my controller and method look like

@

```
Controller('myendpoint')
@ApiTags('MyObject')
@ApiConsumes('application/json')
@ApiProduces('application/json')
@ApiHeader({
  name: 'authorization',
  description: 'Auth token',
})
@UseInterceptors(new JwtInterceptor())
export class MyObjectController {

...
 @Get('/:id')
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'OK',
    type: Content,
  })
  @ApiBadRequestResponse()
  @ApiInternalServerErrorResponse()
  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Get object by id',
    description: 'Get object by id',
    operationId: 'findObjectById',
  }) 
  findObjectById(@Req() req, @Param('id') id: string): Promise<MyObject> {
```

but when the swagger docs are generated, although I'm able to enter an "authorization" header value,

[image]

it doesn't get included with my curl when I click "Execute", which is generated as

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8060/myendpoint/abcdef" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this:
[Updated following breaking/API changes in @nestjs/swagger version 4.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66655649/10313866)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your endpoint header:

`@ApiBearerAuth('Authorization')`

Answer (score 0):

`@ApiHeader()`, `@ApiBasicAuth()`, `@ApiBearerAuth()`, `@ApiOAuth2()`, `@ApiSecurity()`, all of which are found on [this page](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/decorators). Your specific case may vary, but one of these should do the trick.

Comment: I tried ApiHeader since I want this applied to all methods in my controller, but Swagger isn't adding that header in when sending requests from the Swagger UI.  I think it might be related to this -- https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/486 .  Is there another way in?

Comment: Looks like that issue was fixed in `@nestjs/swagger@4.1.1`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using version 4.7.12.  Should I revert to an older version?

Comment: No it should still be fine to use `@ApiHeader()` on a controller.

Comment: I do see a space for me to enter the 'authorization' header value (included screen shot), the issue seems to be when I click "Execute" the header isn't added into the curl request so the call from the Swagger API fails.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the `swagger-ui-express` package, not with the Nest library

Comment: In OpenAPI 3 the `Authorization` header must be defined as a **security scheme** so `@ApiHeader()` won't work - Swagger UI will [ignore](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5643#issuecomment-538412105) header parameters named `Authorization` (as per the spec). If your auth token has the "Bearer" prefix, use `ApiBearerAuth()`. Otherwise try using `@ApiSecurity` + `DocumentBuilder().addApiKey(...)` as in the example here: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/484